# Tapping button to go through each frame of animation

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to create an app where when you tap a button it will go to the next frame in an animation.

I have 8 image files, and when I press the button I want the 1st image to display, and when i press the button again, I want the 2nd image to replace the 1st image and so on.

I was thinking something like:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressDoStuff:(id)sender {
    imageThing.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    imageThing.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    imageThing.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
    imageThing.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"];

}
```

and somehow making this all work consecutively with each press.

I am fairly new at objective c, so any help would be much appreciated.

Can anyone throw up some sample code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this. If you want to do something sequentially, that sounds like the job of an array. So what do you think about this:

In your .h file, add these instance variables:

```
NSMutableArray* picturesArray;
NSInteger counter;
```

And now in your .m file, in your class' init method:

```
//this loop will fill your array with the pictures
for(int idx = 0; idx < NUMBER_OF_PICTURES; idx++) {
    //IMPORTANT: this assumes that your pictures' names start with 
    //'image0.png` for the first image, then 'image1.png`, and so on

    //if your images' names start with 'image1.png' and then go up, then you
    //should change the 'int idx = 0' declaration in the for loop to 'int idx = 1'
    //so the loop will start at 0. You will then need to change the condition
    //to 'idx < (NUMBER_OF_PICTURES + 1)' to accomodate the last image
    NSString* temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", idx];
    UIImage* tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:temp];
    [picturesArray addObject:tempImage];
}
```

and in your `buttonPressDoStuff:` method:

```
//this method will move to the next picture in the array each time it is pressed
-(IBAction)buttonPressDoStuff:(id)sender {
    if(counter < [pictureArray count]) {
        imageThing.image = [picturesArray objectAtIndex:counter];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Your `init` method should look something like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self) {
        //do setup here
        for(int idx = 0; idx < NUMBER_OF_PICTURES; idx++) {
            NSString* temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", idx];
            UIImage* tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:temp];
            [picturesArray addObject:tempImage];
        }
    }
    //it is important that you return 'self' no matter what- if you don't,
    //you will get the 'control reached end of non-void method' warning
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I have seem to run into some issues. Where am I putting the `for(int idx =0....` piece? I have it put in a `-(void)animationArray {...` area, but I feel like this could be the wrong place.. also, the ` @"image%i.png" ` piece.. Am I putting `%i` there to say that its in place for an integer? Or was that just you putting a place holder for me? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The for loop should go in your class' `init` method, which will be called when the instance is created. As for the `%i`, that way a typo. Fixing it now.

Comment: When I put the loop in the `init` method, at the end of the method I get a "Control reaches end of non-void function" warning.. and the pictures are not showing when the action happens.. hmm

Comment: Are you returning self at the end of your init function? I have edited my answer with a abbreviated version of what it should look like.

Comment: Is `counter` supposed to be in the for loop somewhere?

Comment: No. The for loop is just to create the array of images, not to access them. `counter` is declared in your .h file, and is incremented each time the button is pressed, which will change the index of the pictures array being accessed.